# How do I add parsed lines into a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a dictionary where the compiler reads from a text file where there are two words per line. I have parsed it through the split() method but I am struggling on how to add the corresponding keys and values from the line to the dictionary container. I am trying to add it in the ReadStream2() function after doing the split() in the line line.add(rez,rez). I know this is wrong but I have no idea how to combine what I am parsing into the dictionary in terms of keys and values. Thanks!

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> line = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        FileStream filestream = null;
        string path = "Dictionary.txt";
        //WriteByte(filestream, path);
        //ReadByte(filestream, path);
        //WriteStream(filestream, path);
        //ReadFromFile();
        Menu(filestream, path);
        ReadStream2(filestream,path);
        
        Group(filestream, path);
        
    }
   
    static void WriteByte(FileStream filestream, string path)
    {
        string str;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter word");
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            filestream = new FileStream("Dictionary.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            byte[] by = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
            filestream.Write(by, 0, by.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("File written");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            filestream.Close();
        }
    }
    static void ReadByte(FileStream filestream, string path)
    {

        try
        {
            filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] by = new byte[(int)filestream.Length];
            filestream.Read(by, 0, by.Length);
            string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(by);
            Console.WriteLine("File read");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            filestream.Close();
        }
    }
    static void WriteStream(FileStream filestream, string path)
    {
        using (filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
            {
                //string str;
                //Console.WriteLine("Enter word");
                //str = Console.ReadLine();
                //streamWriter.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
    static void ReadStream2(FileStream fileStream, string path)
    {
        using (fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> line = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                string rez = "";
                
                while(sw.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    rez = sw.ReadLine();
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(rez);
                    string[] words = rez.Split(' ');
                    line.Add(rez, rez);
                   
                }
            
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    static void Group(FileStream fileStream, string path)
    {
        
        var list = File
        .ReadLines(path)
        .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
        .GroupBy(p => p.Index / 2)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.First().Value, g => g.Last().Value);
    }
    static void Menu(FileStream fileStream, string path)
    {
        char choice;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome this is a English dictionary press d to continue");
        Console.ResetColor();
        choice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        while (choice == 'd' || choice == 'D')
        {
            ReadStream2(fileStream, path);
        }
    }
    static void askWord()
    {
        string ask;
        Console.WriteLine("What english word would you like to translate");
        ask = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ask == )
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulties to understand.

Are you trying to read the `words` array? `words[0]` and `words[1]`?

```
  string[] words = rez.Split(' ');
  line.Add(words[0], words[1]);
```

Comment: I am trying to make a Key and Value for each line in the text file. So when the user types the word and it matches with a Key of a line it will return the value which is the translation.

Answer (score 0):

@Larrythelobster

I write an sample project, hope I can help you:

```cs
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WelcomeText();

        string path = "Dictionary.txt";
        var dict = ReadFile(path);

        var input = GetInputWord();
        var translateWord = SearchWord(dict, input);

        ShowResult(translateWord);
    }

    private static void WelcomeText()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome! This is a English dictionary...");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, string> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split(' ');
            dict.Add(words[0], words[1]);
        }

        return dict;
    }

    private static string GetInputWord()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to translate: ");
        var word = Console.ReadLine();
        return word;
    }

    private static string SearchWord(IDictionary<string, string> dict, string wordToSearch)
    {
        return dict[wordToSearch];
    }

    private static void ShowResult(string translateWord)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The translate word is: " + translateWord);
    }
}
```

Dictionary.txt (English > French):

```
yellow jaune
red rouge
blue bleu
green vert
```

[image: Console translate word]